# 3D Plotting of Tracks Each Colored Independently From Start To End

Tags: matlab, 3d

I have written a program that plots tracks in 3D given inputs of track Id, Frame number, x, y, and z position from images collected on a microscope. The problem I'm having is best illustrated by this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpdUe.jpg). I'd like each track to be individually labeled from  blue to red independent from each other. What the code below does is link the color scale in all tracks to a single color bar so that a short track is all blue instead of the spectrum from red to blue. I'm a beginner at MATLAB so please be patient with my coding.

My data is organized like below:

```
Tracking    Frame   x    y    z
  1           1     2   151  -49
  1           2     31  139  -61
  1           3     32  113  -41
  2           8     1   10   -2
  2           9     3   28   -63
  2           10    4   25   -60
  2           11    1   20   -50
  2           12    8   20   -55
```

Except each track may have up to a few hundred points within it.

My code is below:

```
input=FileName;  % Rename data for easier use

input.Properties.VariableNames= {'tracking'  'frame'  'x' 'y' 'z'}; 

Max_y=max(input.y)+10;      % This input is the x and y dimensions of the
                            % field of view from the raw data in nm which was analyzed.
Min_y=min(input.y)-10;
Max_x=max(input.x)+10;
Min_x=min(input.x)-10;

ExpsTime=.1;                % Exposure time from camera of raw data frames in seconds
minlength=2;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%        
t=input.frame*ExpsTime;                % Convert frames to time
hold on;                               % plot multiple points and traces on the same graph 
set(gca,'Ydir','normal','FontSize',3);

n=1;                                    % loop counter for moving through different tracks
m=max(input.tracking)+1;                  % total number of different tracks

while n<m              % This loop takes the all the data labeled as a 
                       % single track from the varialbe "tracking" and
                       % plots by connecting the dots from just that track.
   ind1=input(input.tracking==n,:);     % Make subset of data for a single track
   b=size(ind1);                        % Calculates the length in frames of track 
   cnt=linspace(1,b(1),b(1));           % generate sequence of numbers for length of track to count frames within a track
   cnt=cnt';
   cnt=array2table(cnt);                
   ind1=[ind1 cnt];                     % Add info for frame counter to data subset


      if b(1)>minlength                 % Only plot if longer than minlength
       figs(n)= plot3(ind1.x,ind1.y,ind1.z,'-k','LineWidth',1.5);

          scatter3(ind1.x,ind1.y,ind1.z,40,ind1.cnt,'filled')
          axis([Min_x Max_x Min_y Max_y])
          colorbar

          n=n+1 
      else
          n=n+1  %If the track has less than minlength 
                 %number of frames than it is skipped over.
      end

end
```

Comment: Quick hack idea: Re-scale the `ind1` to [0,1] so the colormaps all match.

Comment: Thanks David. Great idea, it works well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David suggested in his comment, scale the intensity of each scatter plot between 0 to 1. you can do that by updating this row:

```
scatter3(ind1.x,ind1.y,ind1.z,40,ind1.cnt,'filled')
```

to this one:

```
scatter3(ind1.x,ind1.y,ind1.z,40,linspace(0,1,numel(ind1.cnt)).','filled')
```

Comment: Thank you, implementing this code does indeed fix the problem. I just had to make one change to your code by replacing the period in the changed code with a close parentheses to make it   _, linespace(0,1,numel(ind1.cnt))',_